# React/Javascript : Maximum Amount Validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

`Number(Amount) > 50000`

The Amount can be in decimal or number. I want to perform a validation on maximum amount which cannot exceed 50000. if I am using Number, then when I enter 50000.1, this is getting satisfied as
Number(Number(50000.1)) is getting converted to 50000. How can I handle this?

Comment: `Number(Number(50000.1))` is still `50000.1`. The problem with your logic is that it's for *minimum* - it returns `true` if the amount is *over* `50000`. https://jsbin.com/sesizurula/edit?js,console

Comment: No, this is not true: "_Number(Number(50000.1)) is getting converted to 50000_"

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses. if amount field is of type text then it can also accept string values. how can I handle that as well.